# Drupal 7.22 Search Form Position

Tags: drupal-7

I am using the Drupal 7.22 and the default search module. I would like to know how to add the search form at the right side in the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Structure---->Blocks---->search form.
in this u can change the search form in anywhere in your website.

Comment: present in your website where you placed search bar.

Comment: If you are using any theme in your website you can see the whole theme places .goto structure--->blocks-->Demonstrate block regions (Professional Theme).then you can place the your search bar in anywhere.